# Python 3.7: How to get the Windows user Login Time?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, authentication

I am trying to get the System User's Login Time using Python 3.7. I have tried win32net and platform module for Python but, functions are not defined in platform module and Win32net is not compatible with Python 3 and more. I have tried following code:

```
import platform
platform.uname()
import platform
os_name = platform.uname()[0].lower()
if os_name == "windows":
   get_win_login_time()
elif os_name.endswith("nix"):
   get_nix_login_time()
```

Comment: Python 3.7 is still in alpha release. You may want to hold your horses and go back to 3.6 for now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Haha! Yes! I am now using Python 3.6 for Django and Jupyter. Otherwise on 3.7, I will be always active on StackOverflow rather than on Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try These ( install win32com.client and subprocess modules first ):

```
import win32com.client, time

strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkLoginProfile")



def Convert_to_human_time(dtmDate):

    strDateTime = ""

    if dtmDate[4] == 0:
        strDateTime = dtmDate[5] + '/'

    else:
        strDateTime = dtmDate[4] + dtmDate[5] + '/'

    if dtmDate[6] == 0:
        strDateTime = strDateTime + dtmDate[7] + '/'

    else:
        strDateTime = strDateTime + dtmDate[6] + dtmDate[7] + '/'
        strDateTime = strDateTime + dtmDate[0] + dtmDate[1] + dtmDate[2] + dtmDate[3] + " " + dtmDate[8] + dtmDate[9] + ":" + dtmDate[10] + dtmDate[11] +':' + dtmDate[12] + dtmDate[13]

    return strDateTime


for objItem in colItems:

    if objItem.Name is not None:
        print("Name: " + str(objItem.Name))

    if objItem.LastLogon is not None:
        print("Last Logon (Normal Format): " + str(objItem.LastLogon))
        print("Last Logon (Human Readable Format): " + Convert_to_human_time(objItem.LastLogon))

    if objItem.LastLogoff is not None:
        print("Last Logoff (Normal Format): " + str(objItem.LastLogoff))
        print("Last Logoff (Human Readable Format): " + Convert_to_human_time(objItem.LastLogoff))

    if objItem.LogonHours is not None:
        print("Logon Hours: " + str(objItem.LogonHours))

    if objItem.LogonServer is not None:
        print("Logon Server: " + str(objItem.LogonServer))

    if objItem.NumberOfLogons is not None:
        print("Number Of Logons: " + str(objItem.NumberOfLogons))
```

Another way :

```
from subprocess import check_output
import sys

get_result = check_output("wmic netlogin get name, fullname, lastlogon", shell=True, stderr=False)

print(get_result)

clean_result = str(get_result).lstrip("b'").rstrip("'").replace("\\r\\r\\n", "\n").replace('\n\n', '\n').split('\n')[2:-1]

for items in clean_result:

    print(items.lstrip().rstrip())
```

Good Luck ...

Comment: Thanks! the second code is running perfectly. Just Displaying format is slightly not aligned. I am able to get what I wanted!
Thanks!